# sql triggers I have error while storing column name in variable and use it for OLD.myvar in sql triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

***MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'TMPCOL' in 'OLD'***

```
BEGIN
DECLARE TOTAL,I INT;
DECLARE CURRENT_CLOUMN VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE TRIGGER_ON_TABLE VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE TRIGGER_OP VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE olddd VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE newwww VARCHAR(255);
SET TOTAL=0;
SET I=0;
SET CURRENT_CLOUMN='atulbaldaniya.com';
SET TRIGGER_ON_TABLE='atulbaldaniya';
SET TRIGGER_OP='UPDATE';
SET olddd='';
SET newwww='';

SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO  TOTAL  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = TRIGGER_ON_TABLE ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
    WHILE I < TOTAL DO
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO CURRENT_CLOUMN FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = TRIGGER_ON_TABLE ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION LIMIT I,1;
        SET olddd=OLD.CURRENT_CLOUMN;
        SET newwww=NEW.CURRENT_CLOUMN;
            IF(olddd != newwww) THEN
                INSERT INTO TMP(DATA1, DATA2)VALUES(TOTAL ,CONCAT('Change in ',olddd,' To ',newwww))
            END IF; 
        SET I=I+1;
    END WHILE ;
END
```

I dont want to
**`INSERT INTO TMP(DATA1, DATA2)VALUES(TOTAL ,OLD.ID);`**
this is working fine.

I want to store column name in a variable and use like **`OLD.MYVAR`**

How can we do like this ?

Comment: You will have to build the SQL statement as a string and the prepare and execute it.

Comment: Thanks, Sagar can you give me an example of a query for this. with using tmp variable where i can change column name

Comment: @AtulBaldaniya as said by Sloan you can prepare statement using string concatenation and then continue.

Answer (score 1):

You would build your query as a string, then prepare it and execute it, something similar to:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO TMP(DATA1, DATA2) VALUES ("DATA",OLD.',TMPCOL,');');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: Thanks but have new error.                                      
MySQL said: #1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `before_employee_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `newjoineeform` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE TMPCOL VARCHAR(100); SET TMPCOL= 'ID'; SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO TMP(DATA1, DATA2) VALUES ("DATA",OLD.',TMPCOL,');'); PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt1; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; END"
MySQL said: #1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: You are correct. Dynamic SQL isn't allowed there. Another way would be to use a case statement (or series of if/then/else) to select which column to get the data from. Another way would be to use a nested if function for the data. Since your question does not include the logic which determines the source column for the data, I can't write an example of either.

Comment: @SloanThrasher , Please check again I have updated my full trigger code

Comment: Do you realize you are consistently misspelling COLUMN as CLOUMN? Also, your logic escapes me, and the code seems pointless. Maybe you should try to explain what you are trying to do. What is the goal of the code? Also, update any error message you are getting since the one in your title doesn't seems to relate to the code currently in your question.