# MySQL said: #1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, subroutine, database-trigger

[This is main question please help me for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505921/sql-triggers-i-have-error-while-storing-column-name-in-variable-and-use-it-for-o?noredirect=1#comment86016419_49505921)

This is my code :

```
BEGIN   

DECLARE TMPCOL VARCHAR(100);

SET TMPCOL= 'ID';   

SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO TMP(DATA1, DATA2) VALUES ("DATA",OLD.',TMPCOL,');');  

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;    

EXECUTE stmt1;   

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;  

END
```

Comment: The error message says it all...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic SQL.  This is effectively the same:

```
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO TMP (DATA1, DATA2)
        VALUES ('DATA', OLD.ID);
END;
```

This should work in a trigger.  Otherwise, `old` is not defined.

Comment: This is nessccessory need this think dynamic otherwise its very easy to use